# Git thinks I am rewriting one of my files everytime I make a small change

Tags: git, diff

I have a medium size Java file. Everytime I make a change to one of my files, BuildTable.java, Git reports it as a massive change, even if is only a line or two. BuildTable.java is about 200 lines and the change in this commit only changed a single line.

git-diff ouputs this:

```
--- a/src/BuildTable.java
+++ b/src/BuildTable.java
@@ -1 +1 @@
-import java.io.FileNotFoundException;^Mimport java.io.FileReader;^Mimport java.io.InputStreamReader;^Mimport java.io.PushbackReader;^Mimport java.util.ArrayList;^Mimport
\ No newline at end of file
+import java.io.FileNotFoundException;^Mimport java.io.FileReader;^Mimport java.io.InputStreamReader;^Mimport java.io.PushbackReader;^Mimport java.util.ArrayList;^Mimport
\ No newline at end of file
```

After doing a git-commit -a

```
Created commit fe43985: better error notifications
 3 files changed, 54 insertions(+), 50 deletions(-)
 rewrite src/BuildTable.java (78%)
```

Is Git seeing this file as binary or something? Is this a problem? If it is, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To fix this, I didn't need to change any of the core git settings, as the default line endings being generated were fine, it was just that this particular file was mangled. To fix it I opened vim and executed the following command

```
:%s/^M/\r/g
```

Note that to type the "^M" you have to type ctrl-V and then ctrl-M.

Comment: I've been searching for days, and you just solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

Clearly, git does not like your mac-style line endings (CR only). Its diff algorithm uses LF as the line separator.

Fix your files to have windows-style (CR LF) or unix (LF only) line endings.

Comment: OS X uses LF endings just like every other style of Unix out there.

Comment: So called "mac-style" line endings were standard on Macs up to MacOS 9. And only on MacOS.

Comment: It's pretty sad this answer was downmodded four times, while the diagnostic was correct, as the question author noted in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Set `core.autocrlf` and `core.safecrlf` with [`git-config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). This will cause git to automatically convert line endings when transferring from/to the object store. You might need to make a commit to store the "new" endings.

Judging from your pasted example, you might be also suffering from "old-style Mac line endings" (thanks to [ddaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11549/ddaa) and [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) for the hint), which are only bare `CR`s without any `LF`, a case not handled by git. If this is true (check with a hex editor), use a tool like [`recode`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/recode) to translate this garbage into some 21st century format, like proper `LF`-only Unix line endings.

Comment: core.autocrlf is not going to help in this case (old-style Mac line endings). To quote the current git source: "We're currently not going to even try to convert stuff that has bare CR characters. Does anybody do that crazy stuff?"

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff -b
```

Ignores end of line changes when showing you the differences.