# Find git commits that "rewrite" files

Tags: git

I noticed this line after I committed something just now:

```
[master 6c15628] <Commit message>
 1 files changed, 49 insertions(+), 44 deletions(-)
 rewrite <filename> (63%)
```

Which I think is really cool, that git knew that I rewrote that file (i.e., the `rewrite <filename> (63%)` part).  This has me more interested.  Is there any git command to get a list of all commits/files that have been "rewritten" by git's standards?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to list all such occurrences, no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040 can offer interesting alternatives, but maybe not *exactly* what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046276/git-rewrite-90 is also related.  It suggests that this is actually a "similarity index".  Actually, search for "similarity" on http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html.  It seems like it should be possible using some of those options and some bash tools, right?

Comment: have you tried `git diff --stat | grep rewrite` ?

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't really have a standard; this is just a UI presentation heuristic. Its output on this point might vary from version or version, or based on various other conditions.

If you wanted, you could probably write a script that used Git's similarity index with some threshold you specify to list the information you're interested in.