# Can't push changes to GitHub 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

**Update:** I couldn't get either of the first two solutions provided to work, so I'm providing more detail and setting a bounty.

I have previously forked a github project called Enki (a Rails blogging platform) and then customized it and deployed it on Heroku.

Now I want to start a new Enki blog. I can't fork Enki again, because it's already forked and customized for the first blog. I now cloned it from the author's page, and wanted to add a new repository on my github page so that I could deploy it to Heroku.  Here's step by step instructions that I followed

```
git clone https://github.com/xaviershay/enki.git valentines
cd valentines
git checkout -b myvalentines
bundle install
cp config/database.example.yml config/database.yml
git init
```

Message

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/mm/Sites/valentines/.git/
```

**1)** Why the existing repository? Did I do something wrong? So it's going into the same repository (as the original fork?) even though I've named it something else?

Made code changes then did

```
git add .
git commit -m "made code changes"
2 files changed, 193 insertions(+), 157 deletions(-)
rewrite Gemfile.lock (70%)
```

**2)** Does the fact that it's writing Gemfile.lock mean that it's not changing the branch but rather the master?

Next I created a repository on GitHub

```
git remote add valentines git@github.com:Username/Valentines.git
git push valentines master
```

As you can see I, following Ksol's suggestion, used a different word than origin but it didn't work **3) Problem -** the GitHub repository 'Valentines' did not show the code changes that I made, but was rather the original gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) git clone will point to the original repository, regardless of the local directory you place it into to. You created a new branch w/ git checkout -b, but it's not a new git repo

2) This looks normal, [rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046276/git-rewrite-90) is just telling you that you made a lot of changes to that file.

3) I believe this is because you didn't push the new branch to your github page

```
git push valentines myvalentines
```

you can also update your .git/config file so origin is your new location. Similarly, there's no reason your master branch need be a copy of the enki master branch, but you should keep a reference to it so you can pull future updates.

Answer (score 4):

Just use another name for your remote than `origin`?

Comment: you mean instead of  "git remote add origin..." I do "git remote add blah...", don't I need to use the word origin?

Comment: No, you don't have. `origin` is just a name. Some programs may treat it in a special manner, though. If you're using command-line interface, you're ok.

Comment: Nope you don't. 'origin' is just an arbitrary name, but commonly used since most repos only have one remote. Running `git remote add [alias] [url]` adds `[url]` under a local remote named `[alias]`. (Cf http://gitref.org/remotes/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Katen's answer:

You can also use branches for this. For example, your forked repo could contain these branches:

```
master (pristine code from the author's repo. You may periodically update this)
blog1 (your first blog)
blog2 (your second blog)
```

This way, to begin working on new installation and customization of this blog engine, just run these commands.

```
// assuming that you completed and committed your work on a current branch
git checkout master // switch to original code
git checkout -b blog3 // "fork" it to a new branch and switch to that branch
```

Comment: I tried this but after the checkout I still ran into the same problem once I tried to put it on github

Comment: This is how you put it to github: `git push origin blog3`. Origin in this case is your forked repo.

Comment: I couldn't get your answer to work. I've updated my OP with more detail. Hope you can assist.