# Git won't diff my main plugin file?

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I'm coming across quite an odd problem. No matter what change I make to a certain file, it always says there's 1 deletion and 1 insertion, which is the entire code of the file for each. This doesn't happen to the other files. This only started happening recently and I'm not sure what could have caused it. Any ideas?

I will explain further if you need me to.

**Edit:** I think I'm getting a little closer to figuring it out. If I type `git diff`, I get something like this:

`<?php^M^M/*^MPlugin Name: SomeName^MPlugin URI: http://...`

So yeah it definitely has something to do with line endings, but how can I get rid of those?

Comment: This sounds like an EOL issue. What line endings are used in the file and which OS are you doing this on?

Comment: Is git not seeing the newlines properly? Is it considering the file to be a single line?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 using PHPStorm IDE. My client told me when he tried downloading the file it made it all one line. Not sure about the line endings...

Comment: Sounds like the file is currently using linux line endings (LF). Maybe your IDE is/was auto converting line endings?

Comment: It's odd because it's only happening to one file, which happens to be the main file in my plugin.

Comment: IS there any `.gitattributes` file with a `core.eol` directive in it?

Comment: Nope, there's no `.gitattributes` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out it had nothing to do with any settings in git but with the file. I found [this answer over at SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251383/566610) that fixed it by opening the file in VIM and entering this command:

`:%s/^M/\r/g` (press `CTRL+V` then `CTRL+M` to get `^M`)

Answer (score 3):

Git tries to figure out if a file is text or binary, but sometimes it gets the wrong answer.  Why?  Hard to say without seeing the file.  Maybe you have a non-ascii character in it, maybe line endings are weird, maybe it got confused.  Either way, when it gets it wrong, time to break out a `.gitattributes` file to avoid the confusion.

If the "main" file in question was named `myfile.c` then you'd create a `.gitattributes` file like this:

```
myfile.c text
```

If all `*.c` files are text, you can just say:

```
*.c text
```

See http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html and [Why does Git treat this text file as a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855712/git-treats-text-file-as-a-binary) and http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: Hmm well I appreciate the answer but I did this and I still get the same result. :(